# iPhone SDK, replace XIB/NIB file onViewDidAppear or anytime during runtime?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, interface-builder

I have an iPhone/iPad app screen which contains two possible layouts that I have defined in two interface builder files (xib/nib). When the app starts, I look in the userdefaults and choose which one to load up.

However if the user chooses the settings button and loads the in app settings menu and changes the layout, then hits the navigation button to go back to the previous screen, how would I change the user interface/xib file to be the new choice without restarting the app?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can force the XIB to load using:

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"XIBName" owner:self options:nil];
```

Edit

Try the following:

Add the following in an utility class which you can use anywhere.

```
+ (id)loadNibNamed:(NSString *)nibName ofClass:(Class)objClass {
    if (nibName && objClass) {
        NSArray *objects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:nibName 
                                                         owner:nil 
                                                       options:nil];            
        for (id currentObject in objects ){
            if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:objClass])
                return currentObject;
        }
    }

    return nil;
}
```

Then make the call like this:

```
MyClass *myClassInstance = [Utility loadNibNamed:@"the_nib_name" 
                                         ofClass:[MyClass class]];
```

See this also: [Single View controller with multiple nibs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4430573/single-view-controller-with-multiple-nibs)

Comment: And this will allow me to continue to use the same viewcontroller file?

Comment: Do I have to call [self viewDidLoad] after?

Comment: Yes, you will somehow need to load the view again or have to add the view as subview to some parent view.

Comment: I've just tried doing this and I am not getting any results. I've added that line to my viewdidappear method and then added after it [self viewDidLoad] and nothing is happening. My old view is still on the screen and functions the same.

Comment: Your example on the call puts it in a class variable. How would I use this to switch the view for the current view controller? To clarify I already created the view controller in the app delegate and I'm in the view controller with the default view. If I want to change the layout but not the controller, I don't think I need to create a new view controller class, I get the impression I can just change the nib directly.

Comment: One way of doing that is, use the default nib as the container and then create 2 different nib files and add them as subviews to the container. That way, the switching would be easier and safe. See here for some clarification: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016944/can-you-swap-the-nib-file-for-a-uiviewcontroller-thats-already-on-screen

Answer (score 0):

```
MyUIViewController *controller;
if (IS_IPAD){
  controller = [[MyUIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyUIViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
} else {
  controller = [[MyUIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyUIViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
}
```

And you can for example push from a navigationController

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

Comment: Would this replace the nib and keep the viewcontroller the same? Kinda like a dynamic layout